# How to find the moment generating function of a random variable X with PDF of 4x^3 for 0<x<1?

Tags: probability, random-variable, moment-generating-function

Let $X$  be a continuous random variable with PDF

\begin{equation}
\nonumber f_X(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
4x^3 & \quad 0 < x \leq 1\\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

How can I calculate the moment-generating function of X and find the third moment?

What I get is
MGF = $e^t * (\frac{4}{t} - \frac{12}{t^2} + \frac{24}{t^3} - \frac{24}{t^4} ) + \frac{24}{t^4}$
But, I can't get the third moment using the MGF function!!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What I get is
MGF = e^t * (4/t - 12/(t^2) + 24/(t^3) - 24/(t^4) ) + 24/(t^4)
But, I can't get the third moment using the MGF function!!

Comment: @JimB when I take the derivative w.r.t t^3 and set t = 0, I got infinity!!

Comment: This is a case where you need to take the limit as $t$ approaches zero.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: You'll probably need to apply L'Hôpital's rule multiple times to obtain the limit.

Comment: Alternatively, express $e^t$ as a power series and perform the multiplication and addition: after the smoke clears, you will find that all powers of $t$ are non-negative.

Comment: This has to be one of the least appetizing ways of computing the third moment for this distribution.  Why not compute it directly as $\int_0^1 x^3(4x^3)\,\mathrm{d}x,$ which you can find instantly?  Is there some point to going through the mgf to obtain the answer?

Comment: @whuber My instructor wants to train us the calculate the moments of a random variable using the MGF function

Comment: That might be a useful exercise in Calculus, but it's of little statistical interest.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).